# Php writing to a single files multiple times per second

Tags: php

We have a php service that should write about 2000 times per second to a file(every http request writes a single line but there are about 2000 requests per second). What is the best way to do it? Is regular file writing fast enough?

Comment: Hmm why use PHP why don't you use your web server log feature?

Comment: What exactly do you wish to log? Do you need to use PHP to capture something and process programmatically some data into each file? What about using the database? Apache logging would be your best bet otherwise. Alternatively, you could log http requests in Apache logs and later process data from those logs with a cron script that runs periodically...

Comment: how much stuff it writes is also a factor.

Comment: We are actually writing events to a text file and amazon kinesis is client is going over that text file data and sending it to s3 and then to redshift